# Initialize generic pointer to struct

Tags: go

Is there anyway to initialize a generic pointer to a struct?

```
func A() (p *Person) {
    p = new(Person)
    return
}

func B[Person any]() Person {
    p := *new(Person)
    return p
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(A()) // Initialized struct
    fmt.Println(B[Person]()) // Initialized struct
    fmt.Println(B[*Person]()) // nil
}
```

How do I also initialize `B[*Person]()` to be a pointer to an empty struct?

How can the generic function handle both Person and *Person? Alternatively, is there a way to prevent users from specifying both, since in most of Go, structs and pointers to structs are interchangeable.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about generics. `How can the generic function handle both Person and *Person` return any ?

Comment: I'm asking how can I write a generic function B that will initialize Person, regardless of if the user passed in *Person or Person as the generic type.

Comment: You already did. You seem to conflate _when_ generics are evaluated: During compile time. A `B[*Person]` "knows" literally nothing about Person. You probably want runtime reflection?

Comment: Reflection would work, but I'm looking for a generic solution for initializing data types where the user can pass in either a struct or a pointer to a struct and the function can handle both cases

Comment: @Matt Using generics-only and given the _type argument_ `*Person`, there is _no way_ to initialize a non-`nil` instance of `*Person` and _no way_ to initialize an instance of `Person`. Either use reflection, or use clear documentation on what the set of acceptable type arguments is.

Comment: @Matt Generics allow for performing identical operations on any type that supports those operations. The operations to initialize an instance of `T` from type arguments `T` and  `*T` are two distinct operations, as is evident from your own attempts (viz. `new(T)` and `*new(T)`).

Comment: *"since in most of Go, structs and pointers to structs are interchangeable."* -- @Matt this is _not true_, unless I misunderstood what you mean by _"in most of Go"_.